# console,clear doesn't clear the screen and reset, I get scrolling

Tags: console

Apologies for this dumb question but mostly other languages I use, when I clear the cmd window, the window is cleared. for console.clear, however, I'm getting a scrolling effect. I'm expecting the window to be cleared and cursor reset to the top; instead the window appears to scroll down and show a blank console. I want the window to remain static, clear, clear it... this is simple win console app, help

```
    Dim k As ConsoleKeyInfo
    Dim x As Integer

    Console.WindowHeight = 500
    Console.WindowWidth = 500

    For x = 1 To 4
        Console.Clear()
        Console.SetCursorPosition(5, 1)
        Console.Write("Hello World!" & x)
        Console.SetCursorPosition(5, 27)
        k = Console.ReadKey
    Next
```

instead the window appears to scroll down and show a blank console.